# Counting the total number of lines except the ones that start with a special character

Tags: python, counting

I want to get the number of atoms from a text file. This text file starts with a couple of lines of header, and sometimes it may add some additional info lines, which also start with special characters. A sample text file looks like this:

```
% site-data vn=3.0
#                        pos
Ga        0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
As        0.2500000   0.2500000   0.2500000
```

My approach was counting the total number of lines and lines that start with special characters, so here is my attempt:

```
def get_atom_number():
    count = 0
    with open(sitefile,'r') as site:
        x = len(site.readlines())
        for line in site.readlines():
            if '#' in line or '%' in line:
                count +=1
return x-count
```

The problem with this function is, with the x (total number of lines) defined, the counter (num. of lines that start with special chars) returns 0. If I delete that line, it works. Now, I can divide these two into two functions, but I believe this should work fine, and I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if '#' in line or '%' in line:` will check if the characters are anywhere in the line. Use `startswith` instead·

```
if line.startswith(('#', '%')):
```

Now, regarding the counting method, you can also increase the counter only when the line is **not** starting with the characters, thus you don't need to know the total number of lines in advance and do not need to consume all the lines:

```
if not line.startswith(('#', '%')):
    counter += 1
```

Then you can directly print the counter at the end

Full code:

```
def get_atom_number():
    count = 0
    with open(sitefile,'r') as site:
        for line in site.readlines():
            if not line.startswith(('#', '%')):
                count +=1
    return count
```

Comment: You could also use `count = sum(1 for line in site if not line.startswith(('#', '%')))`

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing is that `.readlines()` consumes the entire file when it executes. If you call it again, nothing comes out, since it's already at the end of the file.

The solution is to assign `site.readlines()` to a variable, first, and then change the following two lines to refer to that variable. This way, you're only calling it once.

```
def get_atom_number():
    count = 0
    with open(sitefile,'r') as site:
        lines = site.readlines()
        x = len(lines)
        for line in lines:
            if '#' in line or '%' in line:
                count +=1
    return x - count
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you're absolutely right. This makes me wonder, is this a memory friendly approach? Would it still be a logical way, if I was dealing with large files?

Comment: The more memory-efficient approch would be to use @mozway's answer, except iterate over `site` instead of `site.readlines()`. That way, you wouldn't be reading the entire `.readlines()` into memory at all, only one line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `readline` instead

```py
def get_atom_number():
    count = 0
    with open(sitefile,'r') as site:
        for line in site.readline():
            if '#' not in line and '%' not in line:
                count +=1
    return count
```

As mozway's answer, startswith is a better solution, so code can be like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union

IGNORE = ('#', '%')

def get_atom_number(filename: str = sitefile, ignore_chars: Union[str, tuple] = IGNORE) -> int:
    '''Count how many lines in filename that not startswith ignore_chars'''
    return len([1 for i in Path(filename).read_text().splitlines() if not i.startswith(ignore_chars)])
```

Comment: I believe this counts number of characters, not number of lines.

Comment: @user175924 The function can be one line style.

Answer (score 0):

The first call `site.readlines()` in your code at line 4 move the file cursor to the end. So the second call `site.readlines()` at line  5 only get an empty list.
You can try the code below, it saves the result of call `site.readlines()` to a variable `lines`. I think it will be working to solve your problem.

```py
def get_atom_number():
    count = 0
    with open(sitefile,'r') as site:
        lines = site.readlines()
        x = len(lines)
        for line in lines:
            if '#' in line or '%' in line:
                count +=1
    return x - count
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).